# Instantiate excel vba class i get "Compile Error Expected End of Statement

Tags: excel, vba

'''

```
  Set SacarioSymbol= new obSacarioSymbol(SacarioGroupShapes)
```

No Mater what I try I can't get the compile error to clear.

Any help direction will be appreciated!

Comment: That `obSacarioSymbol(SacarioGroupShapes)` seems not be a class name.

Comment: VBA doesn't have parameterized constructors.  Eg see https://nolongerset.com/parameterized-constructors-in-vba/#:~:text=In%20class%2Dbased%20object%2Doriented,to%20set%20required%20member%20variables.